# React renders too much time - Which architecture should I choose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

**My problem:** I am trying to develop a calendar app with React. I have a calendar in the left menu and on the right part: a page for each day. The user can swipe to the next days (I use Swiper.js with one slide per day). The URL must contain the date information (mysite.com/days/2020-12-05) and the current date highlighted in the calendar. I have developped something that works but the day pages are rendered too much time whereas they would only need to be rendered once.

**My architecture**:

- The day page gets the date parameter from the router through the useParams() hook
- When the user swipe to another day I use window.history.pushState(days/new_date) so that the URL is always in line with the day
- When the user swipe to another day I send the date to the calendar of the left menu so that the current date is highlighted in the calendar. To do so I use a callback function to update a state at the root (App.js). Then App.js cascades the date to my calendar with props.
  **=> this causes the app to re-render the whole app, including the day pages that were already rendered. This is not useful.**

**Question:** How should I transfer the date parameter from one component to the another without causing those useless re-render? I need that the URL, the left calendar and the slider day page are always synchronized wathever the user does: enters a new URL, select a date in the calendar or swipe from one day to an other.

**My code:** (simplified as much as possible)

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="app_div">
        <div id='left_menu'>

          <ul>
           // This is a simplified calendar: I can select 3 days and get the info of which date is currently selected
            <li>
              <Link to="/organisation/2020">2020</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/organisation/2021">2021</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/organisation/2022">2022</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              Current date: {date}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="right_frame">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/Organisation/:day">
              <Organisation setDate={setDate}></Organisation>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Organisation">
              <Organisation setDate={setDate}></Organisation>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Organisation.js

```
export default function Organisation(props) {
    let { day } = useParams();
    if (day === undefined) {
        day = 2020;
    }

    return (
        <Swiper
            initialSlide="1"
            onSlideChange={(swiper) => OnSlideChange(swiper, props.setDate)}
        >
            <SwiperSlide daynb={parseInt(day) - 1}><Day day={parseInt(day) - 1}></Day></SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide daynb={parseInt(day)}><Day day={parseInt(day)}></Day></SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide daynb={parseInt(day) + 1}><Day day={parseInt(day) + 1}></Day></SwiperSlide>

        </Swiper>
    );
}

function OnSlideChange(swiper, setDate) {
    window.history.pushState(null, "New Page Title", "/organisation/" + swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex].attributes.daynb.value);
    setDate(swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex].attributes.daynb.value);
}
```

The code is available here https://github.com/Toto5931/react-slides/tree/main/src

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Read about memoization in React, I think it could wolve your performance issues..

Comment: Thanks. Memoization would not work since in each page I will fetch data from an API so the data could change even if the props are unchanged... Isn't it a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way React works - re-renders the whole component if anything in it changes, but remember that React tracks changes in VDOM, so it's very fast.

Also, your `App.js` is just a `Router` component, so saying that it "re-renders the whole app" is exaggeration. It only re-renders the currently displayed component.

Last, but not least, take a look at the `shouldComponentUpdate` function, as it may save you some re-renders (eg. when you don't need to fetch from the API).

Comment: Thanks. Now I know that my logic is consistent with React logic. I should not fear of having too much renders in fact.